# proftpd is accessing my.cnf

Tags: security, ftp, selinux, proftpd

I use proftpd for virtual FTP hosting with MySQL.

I've started writing fine-grained SELinux policies and found that **it's trying to access my.cnf files.**

**Question is what for and why?**

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1378191337.059:153431): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid= comm="proftpd" path="/etc/my.cnf" dev="dm-1" ino=1180081 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1378191337.059:153432): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=50590 comm="proftpd" name="my.cnf" dev="dm-1" ino=1180081 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1378191337.059:153432): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=50590 comm="proftpd" path="/etc/my.cnf" dev="dm-1" ino=1180081 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:mysqld_etc_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Output of `ps auxwf|grep 50590` is empty now - process doesn't exist anymore. Looks like it's trying to do that on every login attempt.

**Update:**
Filed bug/feature request, patch submitted by developer:
http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3971

Comment: are you using `mod_sql`? `proftpd` might be trying to read `my.cnf` files because of that.

Comment: `mod_sql` and `mod_sql_mysql`, WHY does it try to read it

Comment: because you [can store credentials in those files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: Must be, there is nothing else to do, but credentials are specified in `proftpd.conf` as `SQLConnectInfo`. It's  checking my.cnf for that anyway by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add that the source code also mentions this:

I have checked a recent snapshot. Specifically, `proftpd-cvs-20130903/contrib/mod_sql_mysql.c`:

```
485   /* Make sure the MySQL config files are read in.  This will read in
486    * options from group "client" in the MySQL .cnf files.
487    */
488   mysql_options(conn->mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "client");
```

Comment: FYI http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3971

Answer (score 3):

MySQL clients which link against libmysqlclient [read global options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html) from the `[client]` section of `/etc/my.cnf`. This is a typical behavior for such clients, and [ProFTPD is such a client](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html) when you use its MySQL module.

The SELinux boolean `ftpd_full_access` will allow this access, but it also effectively disables SELinux for the entire FTP daemon's operations, so it should not be used without extreme caution.

If it were me, I would file a feature request against `selinux-policy` requesting that a boolean to allow this access be added, or perhaps to add it to the `ftpd_connect_db` boolean.

Comment: http://fpaste.org/36805/37823064/

Comment: FYI http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3971

Comment: I suggested you file a bug against SELinux (in Red Hat).

Comment: and how it's gonna solve the problem? technically

Comment: That depends on how you define the problem. I don't see reading `my.cnf` as a problem; it's generally a good idea.

Comment: I define problem this way: If I don't want to allow it to read it, then my logs get filled.

Answer (score 1):

From the off doc

**Question**: How do I configure `mod_sql` so that it will use encrypted connections (*e.g.* SSL/TLS) to the backend database server?
**Answer**: If you are using MySQL, then you can configure this in the **[client]** section of your `my.cnf` configuration file.

That's why proftpd try to read /etc/my.cnf